# what is correct format of bundle identifier in iOS?

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

I have four bundle identifier

1. com.company.appname
2. com.appname
3. appname
4. com.company-name.app-name

Please help me to find out correct bundle identifier,
Please tell me which is correct.

Comment: As per my view 3rd is wrong.. others are proper... I prefer first one..

Comment: all other are incorrect format?

Comment: Nope. I said dear... others are proper. I prefer fitst one and first one is standard format.. you can use '-' but is not standard way.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

All the formats which you have mentioned are correct and can be used as bundle identifier. But the standard format followed is `com.company.appname` (reverse domain name).

Comment: Can we use `org` as a prefix instead of `com`

Comment: Yes, you could.

Comment: And then Apple comes along and just adds "iCloud" (iCloud.com.company.appname), and completely destroys this beautiful all lower case identifier. (when adding CloudKit, default container name) 

Comment: @d4Rk Yeah. Now I'm not sure whether to go lowercase or CamelCase for my app name.

Answer (score 6):

The First type is the correct one.It is a standard to use the reverse domain name as the bundle identifier along with app name.
For example com.google.gmail,com.fb.messanger

Answer (score 4):

> The Bundle ID can only contain alphanumeric characters, hyphens, and
>   periods. It can't end on a period.

[image]

This regexp should be correct: `.[\w\.-]+[\w-]`

Answer (score 0):

all you need is device registered at Apple development program, if you have no device registered simply connect your iphone and register it through xcode.