# Vuforia iOS sample code build error with failed to create provision profile

Tags: ios, xcode, vuforia

I have not joined the Apple Developer Program but filled the team information with my own apple ID in my XCode project settings.  The XCode project was able to run and deploy.

When I downloaded the Vuforia sample source code and built the project, I got the following error:

```
Failed to create provisioning profile
```

I tried to Google this to confirm if the Apple developer program is mandatory for Vuforia SDK.

If anyone knows more information on this, please let me know.

Comment: Is the problem not clear? can anyone help for this?
First question in stack overflow, hope can be resolved :)

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603667/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile)