# Xcode app won't build after upgrade to 12.3

Tags: xcode

I have a simple WebView app that would build in Xcode and worked. I noticed the Apple Store had "Update" under Xcode so I did. The new version is 12.3, and I actually think my previous version was 12.3 as well, if it wasn't it was 12.n! Didn't really need an upgrade just thought why not. I am not doing anything fancy whatsoever, single view app with storyboard and just one view controller with simple code.

Now my app won't build, the device simulators are all gone, and I get these errors about my provisioning profile whatever that is.

Showing Recent Messages
Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

Showing Recent Messages
No profiles for 'com.playpen.playpen' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.playpen.playpen'.

I am brand new to the Apple world and Xcode, everything is frustrating and mysterious. Can someone please tell me how to get my device simulators back, profile back, and my app building and running again.

Thanks

Comment: For the provisioning profile thing, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39603822/14351818) out. For the simulators not appearing, you can re-add them again like [this](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/blob/master/GetNewSimulator.gif).

Comment: I reinstalled the simulators and rebooted, that fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make sure you have the device set to a simulator instead of a physical device. You have to have the physical device plugged in for the program to run, plus it's just trickier than the simulators.
If it says something like iPhone click on it and select one of the simulators from the dropdown.

The next thing to try is to change the bundle identifier. From the file explorer on the left side, click on the project file (has an Xcode icon next to it) and go to Signing & Capabilities. Make sure you have a Team selected and a Bundle Identifier filled in.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was there were no simulators, reinstalled them and rebooted and that fixed it. I check out the bundle advice.