# Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching [app name]

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode12, apple-developer

I am seeking help in resolving the Xcode 12 error message

> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles

I registered for a paid Apple Developer account and I am following the steps to prepare my app for distribution. One of the steps involves going to Xcode and selecting *"Any iOS Device (arm64)"* as the simulator and then clicking Product > Archive. When I click Archive, however, my build consistently fails. I receive the below two error messages:

> Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered
> in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device
> to have Xcode register it.

And

> No profiles for '[bundle id]' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS
> App Development provisioning profiles matching '[bundle id]'.

[Screenshot of error messages in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1gAu.png)

Can anyone advise how to fix this problem? This is my first time trying to submit something on the app store.

I am not using Flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI I ended up fixing this by plugging my iPhone into my computer and running the app in Xcode. Xcode gave me a pop-up warning that my device was not registered. I clicked the "Register" button and all the errors were resolved.

Comment: So, there is no way to build ios app without ios device?

Comment: duplicate link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603667/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile/40314777

Comment: While using "Archive" XCode project I selected my phone instead of "Any iOS Device (arm64)"