# Failed to create provisioning profile for IOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, xcode8, appium-ios

Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Select a device run destination to have Xcode register it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to create provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603667/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 2):

As far as you don't require provisioning profile to run app in Simulator.

Select iPhone Simulator in Xcode.

[image]

If you want to run application on Device,

On Signing and Capabilities select 'Automatically Sign' option.
[image]

Connect your Device, On settings 'Add This Device.'
Xcode will Automatically create Profile.

Comment: Thanks that is resolved now but facing new issue while launching the safari browser from code error - [WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1664700673167 (14:21:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65

Comment: @Akash: Please ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

Dacing new issue while launching the safari browser from code
error -
[WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1664700673167 (14:21:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65
[XCUITest] xcodebuild error message: