# Invalid Bundle when trying to upload application for beta testing using Testflight

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I'm trying to upload my iOS application for beta testing using Testflight. However, I'm encountering errors saying that my bundle is invalid. When I change my Executable file in Info.plist to a different name, it gives me an error that Info.plist doesn't exist. But when I use $(EXECUTABLE_NAME) for the executable file, It gives me an error shown in the picture. I've had so many attempts in here already, I don't what's going wrong anymore. Thanks!

[image: Error1]

This is my Info.plist
[image: Info.plist]

This is the general settings

[image: Gen1]

[image: Gen2]

Comment: Show the general settings of your project target.

Comment: Posted the general settings :) @Nitish

Comment: Your bundle identifier is incorrect.

Comment: How do I know the correct bundle identifier? @Nitish

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979874/what-is-correct-format-of-bundle-identifier-in-ios

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is correct format of bundle identifier in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979874/what-is-correct-format-of-bundle-identifier-in-ios)

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: @Nitish still having the same error.. I've already changed my bundle identifier