# eas build fails with "The Bundle Identifier "org.name.[myappname]" is not available to team ... Change it in your app config and try again

Tags: ios, xcode, expo

I have an expo managed app. I am trying to do a build using EAS. I have already registered my device and created the app on Apple's App Store Connect. However when I try to run the following command:

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

I keep getting the following error and for the life of me I can't figure out what is causing it:

> The bundle identifier org.name.frontend is not available to team ...,
> change it in your app config and try again.
> UnexpectedAppleResponse: An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value - An App ID with Identifier 'org.name.myapp' is not
> available. Please enter a different string.

I have no idea where the "org.name" piece is coming from. I never used that and now it is throwing errors. Any suggestions? (my bundleidentifier in app.json is not this value)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem myself when running `eas build --platform ios` one of the prompts asked for bundleIdentifier and I accidentally entered a name that's not in the Apple pattern.

To change it just go to the bundleIdentifier in your app.json and change it to: `com.your-apple-org-name.your-app-name` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979874/what-is-correct-format-of-bundle-identifier-in-ios) and run `eas build --profile development --platform ios` again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a wildcard universal app distribution certificate (com.yourcompany.*) in your organisation. And you are trying to use a bundle identifier thats new to your company, maybe youre setting up a new project or using a different bundle id for different environments, try running the the eas command through with an Apple Developer Admin Account.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a search and find the instances of bundle identifiers in the error message in project.pbxproj file under `YourApp/ios/[YourApp].xcodeproj`.